# Cylic group of order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to check $\dfrac{D_{4}}{N}$ is isomorphic to the cylic group of order $2$.
However, I just want to check if $\mathbb{Z}_2 $is the cyclic group of order 2 since it is not specified.
Thank you.

Comment: All groups of order two are pairwise isomorphic.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Take your two favourite groups $A$ and $B$ of order two. There are two group homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$. One is the zero map, the other is an isomorphism.

Comment: to add a detail to the given answers for any order there is only one (up to isomorphism) cyclic group with the given order, which implies that every cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (and an infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to isomorphism there is only one group of order $2$ and that group is the cyclic group of order two.  To see this let $G = \{e, x\}$ be a group of order $2$, where $e$ is the identity element and $x \neq e$.

The element $x^2$ must be either $x$ or $e$ because these are the only two elements in the group.  We cannot have $x^2 = x$ because cancelling $x$ gives $x = e$ and we have assumed that $x \neq e$.  Thus we must have $x^2 = e$.

But then $G = \langle x\rangle$ and $x^2 = e$ so $G$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.